# Alternative proofs for the higher product rule (differentiation)

Tags: derivatives, alternative-proof

Let $f,g$ be smooth functions.

I'm looking for proofs for the formula
$$
\left(\frac d {dx}\right)^n f(x)\cdot g(x) =
 \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{ i} f^{(i)}(x)\cdot g^{(n-i)}(x) 
$$
, where $f^{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-th derivation of $f$.

The classical proof uses induction, and runs analogue to the proof of the binomial theorem. It can be found here:
[Proof 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule#Proof)

---

The second proof that is easily possible is by creating a bijection between 
$$
\binom{\{1,..,n\}}{k} = \{M\subseteq \{1,..,n\}\mid |M| =k\}
$$
and the ways to create a single term $f^{(k)}(x)\cdot g^{(n-k)}(x)$.

The argument is roughly this:
We can view each set $M\in \binom{\{1,..,n\}}{k} $ as list of all the times we derived $f$ instead of $g$:

Say e.g. $M =\{1,2,4\}\in \binom{\{1,..,4\}}{3}$, i.e. especially $n=4, k=3$. 
Then that 'traces' the path

$\begin{align*}
 &f^{(0)}(x)\cdot g^{(0)}(x)\\
\to &f^{(1)}(x)\cdot g^{(0)}(x)\\
\to &f^{(2)}(x)\cdot g^{(0)}(x)\\
\to &f^{(2)}(x)\cdot g^{(1)}(x)\\
\to &f^{(3)}(x)\cdot g^{(1)}(x)
\end{align*}$

Each such path tracks one summand in the expanding of 
$\left(\frac d {dx}\right)^n f(x)\cdot g(x)$
 if we don't simplify the terms (i.e. add up terms of the same type). 
One then has only to show that the paths are injective and surjective.

---

Proof 3:

We define $M:=\{f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \mid f \text{ smooth}\}$.

Using this set, we now define the polynomial ring $\mathbb R[M]$. In other words, we look at the functions now as nothing more than formal objects, equipped with a commutative and associative addition.

The idea is now this: Instead of looking at the product $f\cdot g$, we look at formal pairs $(f,g)$, which we interpret as a multiplication of its elements. On these we then define a differentiation, construct a recursion, and then solve it.

First, we formalize the differentiation-operator to a function $\partial:\mathbb R[M]^2 \to \mathbb R[M]^2$ (we'll only formalize the parts of it that we need).

For this, we define:
$$
\partial_l:\mathbb R[M]^2\to \mathbb R[M]^2,\qquad (f^{(i)},g^{(j)})\mapsto 
(f^{(i+1)},g^{(j)})
\\
\partial_r: \mathbb R[M]^2\to \mathbb R[M]^2
,\qquad (f^{(i)},g^{(j)})\mapsto 
(f^{(i)},g^{(j+1)})
$$

I.e. $\partial_l$ is the differentiates the left element of the tuple, and $\partial_r$ the right element of the tuple.

On the pairs $\mathbb R[M]^2$ we define a commutative & associate addition as well, which though can only be simplified if both summands are identical:
$$
(f^{(i)},g^{(j)}) +(f^{(i)},g^{(j)}) = 2 (f^{(i)},g^{(j)})
\\
(f^{(i)},g^{(j+1)}) + (f^{(i)},g^{(j)}) = (f^{(i)},g^{(j+1)}) + (f^{(i)},g^{(j)})
$$

Now $\partial$ is simply:
$$
\partial = \partial_l + \partial_r
$$

One can show, that $\partial$ is linear, and that $\partial_l,\partial_r,\partial$ all are commuting with each other.

If we define $\partial^n$ as applying $\partial$ $n$ times, the original problem now is:
$$
\partial^n (f,g) =   
 \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{ i} \partial_l^i \partial_r^{n-i} (f,g)
$$

We can use the definition of $\partial$ to formulate the recursion:
$$
\begin{align*}
\partial^n (f,g) &= \partial^{n-1} (\partial_l(f,g)+\partial_r(f,g)) = 
\\ &=
\partial_l\partial^{n-1}(f,g) + \partial_r\partial^{n-1}(f,g)
\\
&=(\partial_l + \partial_r)\partial^{n-1}(f,g)
\end{align*}
$$

This is equivalent to
$$
\partial^n (f,g) -(\partial_l + \partial_r)\partial^{n-1}(f,g) = 0
$$

This leads to the closed formula of the generating function $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n$:
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n = \frac{1}{1-(\partial_l + \partial_r)x}
$$

It is now easy to obtain $a_n = (\partial_l + \partial_r)^n (f,g)$, which is what we wanted to show, albeit in a totally different notation.

(This proof is still far from perfect, and any improvements/suggestions are welcome)

---

What are other proofs to show the higher product rule?

Comment: It's easier to use induction on $n.$ You can easily see that $$\left(\frac d {dx}\right)^n f(x)\cdot g(x) =
 \sum_{i=0}^n a_{n,i}f^{(i)}(x)\cdot g^{(n-i)}(x)$$ for some constants $a_{n,i},$ and then prove that $a_{n.i}$ satisfies the inductive definition of $\binom{n}{i}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So a more generalized induction that says "We know there's something going on there, just not exactly what". Should be interesting, though for the induction to give a result, we'll need to solve the recurrence $a_{n+1,i}=a_{n,i}+\binom{n}{i-1}$ somewhere in the proof